# why my up function changes input out of its block in Java

Tags: java

i wrote a function to change an input matrix and return the changed matrix in java.
but when i want use input matrix after calling this function, i see that my input matrix has been changed.
My Up Function:

```
char[][] up(char[][] state, int[] empty){

    int ie = empty[0];
    int je = empty[1];

    if(tools.checkMoves(state,1,ie,je)){
        state[ie][je] = state[ie-1][je];
        state[ie-1][je] = '0';
    }else{
        System.out.println("Move not allowed");
    }

    return state;
}
```

print matrix then call function and again print matrix

```
System.out.println(gameGenerator.printGame(nextState));
    System.out.println(gameGenerator.printGame(moves.up(nextState,tools.getEmpty(nextState))));
    System.out.println(gameGenerator.printGame(nextState));
```

Answer is:
1.print input matrix

```
-------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 7 | 6 |
| 4 |   | 8 |
-------------
```

2.print matrix returned from function

```
-------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 5 |   | 6 |
| 4 | 7 | 8 |
-------------
```

3.print input matrix after calling up function and it's CHANGED!

```
-------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 5 |   | 6 |
| 4 | 7 | 8 |
-------------
```

please help ! Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying your input matrix in those two lines:

```
state[ie][je] = state[ie-1][je];
state[ie-1][je] = '0';
```

Java is an object-oriented language. When you pass an object to a method, you pass its reference. The reference is copied but not the object itself. When you modify the object inside the method, it is still modified after the method (which is normal since it is the same object).

If you don't want your method to create any side effect, you have create a copy of the matrix at the beginning of your method and modify the copy.

---

**Additional note:**

You may wonder why when the input is a primitive type, then the value is still the same outside the method, like this:

```
public void modify(int i){
  i = 5;
}
```

That's because Java is *pass by value*, which means that the value of *i* is copied when the method is called, so only the copy is modified. As I wrote above, objects references are also passed by value, which means that the reference is copied. (to explain it roughly, you copy the value of the pointer to the object).

If you'd like a more detailed explanation, you can read this : http://www.javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Comment: Yes i did this after i posted this question. so this is right way. thanks a lot

Comment: but just a thing, this not happened when is use a function with integer return type
for example a function gives a number and then multiplies it by -1 and return it.

Comment: I edited my answer to explain the difference with primitives